# Select that does not work in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table mysql called EVOLUTIONS which has, between other, s two fields called I NUMBER and IT DATES. The field NUMBERED it is INT NOT NULL and the field DATES it is DATE NOT NULL. The matter is that I have a judgment sql pa which must take a field called EVOL of the above mentioned table when NUMBER is equal to the Xth number and DATE is equal the Xth date. The format of DATE is aaaa-mm-dd When the NUMBER modified the judgment for tome in account only it works but it does not do it when the criterion is A DATE. In conceto the judgment and the code php is:

```
<?php
    $v1 = isset($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : null ;
    $v1 = $_SESSION['codigos'];
    $fechasevopas = isset($_POST['fechapas']) ? $_POST['fechapas'] : null ;
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Consulta")or  die ('Error de conexion: ' . mysqli_error());
    $result= mysqli_query($link,"SELECT EVOL FROM EVOLUCIONES WHERE NUMERO='$v1' AND FECHA='$fechasevopas'");
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<textarea name='comentario' rows='14' cols='92'>$row2[0]   </textarea>" ;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: Is your query working in your database?

Comment: The value of DATE for any reason is not taken. Not if it will be necessary to see with the type of fact that is of type DATE. When I write in the code the following thing: I begin ' SELECT EVOL FROM EVOLUTIONS WHERE NUMBERED ' $v1 ' AND IT DATES ' $fechasevopas "; sindo the value of $v1 1 and of $fechasevopas 2015-05-18 the screen prints SELECT EVOL FROM EVOLUTIONS WHERE I NUMBER ' 1 ' AND IT DATES ". That is to say the value of $fechasevopas does not take it in account.